# How to make the square root symbol in axes labels?

Tags: r, plotmath

How can I make the square root symbol to appear ceiling an axis label in R?

Answer (score 17):

Use `expression(sqrt(x))`, see the [help file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) (by doing `?plotmath` as mentioned in mnel's comment) for mathematical annotations in R plots.

```
plot(1:10,
     main='Example',
     ylab=expression(sqrt(x)))
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: +1. There is no need to look online for the help. `?plotmath` will give the same help page

Comment: I'm downvoting (the question, not the answer) because @user1730122 crossposted to r-help.